# Optimize area of football field within running track of 400 meters in perimeter

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> We are projecting a running track. The running area consists of two
>   parallel lines and two semicircles connecting them. The perimeter of
>   the running track is 400 meters. We want to have a football playground
>   (a rectangle) inside the running track with the biggest possible area.
>   What dimensions do we have to choose in order to have the biggest
>   area?

I know how to optimize using the derivative, however I don't know how to form the function.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be the radius of the semicircle and $d$ the parallel length. Then, with $2d+2\pi r=400$, the rectangle area is

$$A(r)=2rd=r(400-2\pi r)$$

Set the derivative $A’(r)=400-4\pi r=0$ to obtain the optimal radius $r=\frac{100}{\pi}$ meters and the corresponding straight length $d=100$ meters.

Answer (score 1):

Say the rectangle has sides $x$ (the straight segment of track) and $y$. The constraint is that the track needs to be 400m long. The length is $2x+\pi y $ (two segement plus the two semicircles with diameter $y$. So $2x+\pi y=400.$ That is, 
$$
y=\frac{400-2x}\pi. 
$$
You want to maximize the area of the rectangle, that is you want to maximize
$$
f(x)=xy=\frac{400x-2x^2}\pi. 
$$

Comment: Thanks. But I am unsure about one thing. Why is length $2x+\pi y$? I understand that we have two straight segments, that's why $2x$ but why not $2 \pi y$, since we also have two semicircles?

Comment: Because $y$ is the diameter, not the radius.